# Symfony2: Exception - Unable to find the controller for path

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-2.3

I added a new action to my controller, created the twig file and added the corresponding route to the `routing.yml` file. However I can't make it work. I keep getting:

> Unable to find the controller for path /route/1/change

What am I missing?

```
# app/config/routing.yml

engineering_change:
    pattern: /engineering/{id}/change
    defaults: { controller: MgmtBundle:Engineering:change }
```

I generate the url in my template like this:

```
{{ path('engineering_change', { 'id': entities.id }) }}
```

Comment: I did all of that before I posted. I added tons of other actions on days before and I missed the _ on controller -_-"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should read `_controller` instead of `controller` in your `routing.yml`.

-> [Routing in Action](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-in-action)

Comment: oh, what an idiot i am. I can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks.